# Is empty set a subset of every subset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Trvially, the empty set $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set $V$(say). Does it mean that $\emptyset$ is also a subset of every subset of $V$? i.e , if $A$ is an arbitrary subset of $V$, then will it be right to say that $\emptyset$ $\subseteq A$?

Comment: Every bag can be made empty by removing things from it, but not every bag literally has an empty bag inside it. (The bags analogy is only helpful up to a point, but I think it is helpful here.)

Comment: By "belongs to" -- do you mean "is an element of" or "is a subset of"?

Comment: Probably a handful of other questions are also good as duplicates.

Comment: If a statement is true for all *sets*, and a subset of a set is in particular *a set* (it is a sub-*set*), then the statement is true for all subsets of a given set as well, yes.

Answer (score 3):

No: $\emptyset \notin \emptyset$ (but $\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset$).

Comment: do you mean that empty set is a subet of every subset? If so, i will be done

Comment: @gete Yes - a subset, but not necessarily an element.

Comment: @gete I interpreted "belongs to" as "is an element of". You might want to update your question, if you meant something else

Comment: @bruderjakob17 my question was a bit wrongly framed anyways, i think Noah Schweber has got the answer in his comment. I am editing my pose.